# What browsers are rfc 6265 comliant

Tags: asp.net, browser, rfc6265

I'm looking for a list of  rfc 6265 compliant browsers.  I asked Mr. Google and apparently this is not an easy answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how this information would help you. I mean perhaps version 5 of browser A is not compliant but version 5.3.4 is. What is this good to you? You can't know what version a client has installed and uses.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find is this site: https://inikulin.github.io/cookie-compat/ which lists browsers per feature.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, and I may be wrong on this, but RFC 6265 does not need to be implemented by any particular browser.  RFC 6265 cookie values are defined so that they will work with any browser that implements any of the Cookie RFCs.

Iff you try to use cookie values that don't conform to RFC 6265, you may find that cookie behavior varies with different browsers.

I think if you just conform to RFC 6265 you will be alright.

Comment: They do, in fact, need to implement some changes defined in 6265. An example is the domain attribute behavior in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139)